# Use of <aura:locator> and <aura:locatorContext> components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Browsing `forcedotcom/aura` GitHub repo I faced some interesting components

> `<aura:locator>`
>
> `<aura:locatorContext>`

Then I inserted some meaningless snippet into my `foo.cmp` lightning component and **It deployed** without any error:

```html
<aura:locator target="anchor" alias="menu-item" isPrimitive="true" description="Action item button">
        <aura:locatorContext key="devNameOrId" value="{!v.id}"/>
</aura:locator>
```

So that means that these components are supported by Lightning Aura Framework and compatible within lightning components. I didn't find any docs or mentions about them.

So the questions are:

> Is there any useful application of `<aura:locator>` and `<aura:locatorContext>`?
>
> How do they work and what are their attributes responsible for?

Comment: it is referenced here with comment that it is for performance -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_lightning_components_prechat_sample_aura.htm

Comment: Yes, that's the only place it appeared in docs. However the comment `<!-- For Aura performance -->` literally says n0thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short version*: Salesforce customers cannot do anything with those components as the necessary APIs to leverage them are not exposed (anymore). In the framework they seem to be used to better handle/identify the transaction context in nested component situations.

*Long version*:

I checked [the original commit](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/commit/253b4960451830494558ac2ace32f8edfac8655c#diff-9880c1082574512f215bd2e5605dd0f3) for this component.

The test description for the locator components reads:

```
     /**
     * 1. Click on an element contained inside another component that is included in our component.
     * 2. Get the transaction that happened as a result of clicking on the element.
     * 3. Verify the target of the transaction is the element we clicked on.
     * 4. Verify the scope is the component that contained the actual element.
     * 5. Verify the context information is as expected.
     */
```

In this commit, I also learned about `component.prototype.getLocator(localId)` or `.getLocatorDefs()` and especially `.resolveLocator()` as part of the `AuraExpressionService` or `AuraComponentService` - neither of which are accessible (anymore) on the platform.

`resolveLocator` seems to be the main 'feature' here, which gives you a bunch of information:

```
* @returns This will produce a locator that combines information as such:
 *          + root localId as target with context provided by parent->root locator
 *          + parent localId as scope with context provided by grandparent->parent locator
 */
```

Still not satisfied, I tried to rebuild one of the test components:

```
/* locator.cmp*/ 
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="innerTextValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="addText" default="someText" type="String"/>

    <aura:locator target="innerWithAuraIdLocator" description="Inner Div Locator">
        <aura:locatorContext key="innerTextValue" value="{!v.innerTextValue + v.addText}"/>
    </aura:locator>

    <div class="innerWithAuraIdLocator" aura:id="innerWithAuraIdLocator" onclick="{!c.clickHandler}">
        {!v.innerTextValue + ' | inner has auraid and locator'}
    </div>

    <div class="innerWithAuraIdNoLocator" aura:id="innerWithAuraIdNoLocator" onclick="{!c.clickHandler}">
        {!v.innerTextValue + ' | inner has auraid without locatordef'}
    </div>

    <div class="innerWithoutAuraId" onclick="{!c.clickHandler}">
        {!v.innerTextValue + ' | inner has NO auraid'}
    </div>

    <div class="innerWithAuraIdDataRef" aura:id="innerWithAuraIdDataRef" onclick="{!c.clickHandler}">
        {!v.innerTextValue + ' | inner has auraid without locator def but uses data-refid'}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```
/*locatorController.js*/
({
    clickHandler: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        // do nothing, but we do need this handler 
        // setup so that click handlers are added
    }
})
```

```
/*locatorRenderer.js*/
({
    render: function (cmp) {
        var ret = this.superRender();
        var element = ret[3];
        element.setAttribute("data-refid", "keyRef");
        element.setAttribute("data-keyRef", cmp.get("v.innerTextValue"));
        return ret;
    }
})
```

And put it into a `testApp`

```
/*testApp.app*/
<aura:application extends="force:slds">

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:button label="Click Me" onclick="{!c.onClick}" aura:id="clickMeButton"/>
    </div>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wrapperText" default="Inner Text Set from locatorWrapper" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentKeyAppend" default=" abc" type="String"/>

    <aura:locator target="locatorWrapperIdWithDef" description="Locator defined on wrapper">
        <aura:locatorContext key="parentKey" value="{!v.wrapperText}"/>
    </aura:locator>

    <div class="locatorWrapperIdNoDef">
        <c:locator aura:id="locatorWrapperIdNoDef" innerTextValue="{!v.wrapperText + ' | Parent has auraid without locator def'}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="locatorWrapperNoAuraId">
        <c:locator innerTextValue="{!v.wrapperText + ' | Parent does NOT have auraid'}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="locatorWrapperIdWithDef">
        <c:locator aura:id="locatorWrapperIdWithDef" innerTextValue="{!v.wrapperText + ' | Parent has auraid with locator def'}"/>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

```
/*testAppController.js*/
({
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
    },

    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        //empty
    }
})
```

It all compiles fine and displays but that is as far as I got. Whereas I could simulate a click as [in the aura test](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/253b4960451830494558ac2ace32f8edfac8655c/aura-components/src/test/components/locatorTest/locatorWrapper/locatorWrapperTest.js), I have no `metricsService` to verify the transaction context myself. 
As explained above, the necessary APIs/functions on component level to actually use `locatorContext` are not exposed within Salesforce.

As for the appearance of `aura:locator` in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_lightning_components_prechat_sample_aura.htm) for the pre-chat ui, I am guessing that the pre-chat interface`lightningsnapin:prechatUI` makes use of `aura:locator` to handle interaction within its nested structure more gracefully.